# Is PBKDF2 only SHA1 in C#?

Tags: cryptography, hash, .net, pbkdf2, sha256

I can't find a way of specifying the hashing algorithm used by the PBKDF2 ([the Rfc2898DeriveBytes class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes.aspx)) implementation in C# `System.Security.Cryptography`.

It seems to be just SHA1. Am I missing something? I was hoping to use PBKDF2-SHA256.

Comment: Why do you prefer PBKDF2-SHA256? The technical benefits are rather small, even PBKDF2-MD5 isn't broken yet. The main benefit I see is PR.

Comment: How is PBKDF2-MD5 not considered broken? That's insanity.

Comment: Why do you consider it broken? I wouldn't recommend using it, but I'm not aware of any faster than brute-force attack on it. MD5's pre-image resistance is still pretty strong, certainly much stronger that almost all passwords.

Comment: MD5 is considered insecure due to collision attacks and extension attacks.

Comment: Extension attacks apply equally to SHA-2. But neither length extensions, nor collisions are relevant to password hashing. For password hashing only first pre-images are relevant, and MD5 is still quite strong in that regard. There is no practical attack faster than simply guessing the password against PBKDF-2-MD5.

Comment: You may be correct that the known issues with MD5 don't currently apply to password hashes (although it's close enough to be considered a broken algorithm), but the point of the hash is to make it computationally expensive to brute, and MD5 is computationally cheap.

Comment: @FooParty SHA1 and SHA2 are about as cheap. It's the PBKDF2 part that makes it computationally expensive. You need a preimage-resistant hash in PBKDF2, and MD5 is ok for that.

Comment: @FooParty That's why PBKDF2 takes a work factor. If you tune this parameter so that hashing on the legitimate system takes equally long for PBKDF2-MD5 and PBKDF2-SHA-256, then MD5 being cheap isn't very relevant anymore. There are much bigger gains by switching to scrypt or bcrypt which reduce the advantage of specialized hardware over the legitimate system.

Comment: I guess I'm missing some bit of information on what makes PBKDF2 special other than being FIPS certified.

Comment: @FooParty PBKDF2 isn't the only secure way to hash a password using standard functions (SHA1, MD5, etc.). What's important is that **it's reasonably secure at all** -- which is more than you can say about most methods people come up with.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [this blog post](http://www.jmedved.com/2012/04/pbkdf2-with-sha-256-and-others/): the author has apparently observed the same lack of SHA-256 support in [the `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes%28v=vs.100%29) of .NET, and set out to write his own code. (I have not looked at that code and cannot vouch for its quality.)

Otherwise, it would not be too hard to reimplement PBKDF2 with HMAC/SHA-256, following the description of [RFC 2898](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2898), section 5.2. .NET includes an [implementation of HMAC/SHA-256](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hmacsha256%28v=vs.100%29).

Comment: I know better than to roll my own crypto.

Comment: @FooParty but you could implement a specification and in/out test it against other implementations.

Answer (score 0):

In 2022 you can choose the hashing algorithm like this:

```
byte[] key = Rfc2898DeriveBytes.Pbkdf2(password, salt, 1000000, HashAlgorithmName.SHA512, 32);
```

Where salt should be a random byte array.

The last number is the length of the key.